# How to show bars in ggplot2 in descending order of a numeric vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rank

```
df <- data.frame (Categories=c("Alpha Category", "Alpha Category", 
                               "Alpha Category", "Bravo Category", 
                               "Bravo Category", "Bravo Category", 
                               "Charlie Category", "Charlie Category", 
                               "Charlie Category"),  
                  choices=c("alpha1", "alpha2", "alpha3", "bravo1", 
                            "bravo2", "bravo3", "charlie1", "charlie2",
                            "charlie3")  , 
                  ratings=c(20,60,40, 55,75,25,65,35,45))    
df.plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Categories, ratings, fill = choices))
           + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") 
           + coord_flip()    
df.plot <- df.plot 
           + theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "")  
           + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")    
df.plot <- df.plot 
           + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=10),limits=c(0,80) )  
           + ylab("Ratings")  
           + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=16)) #change font size of y axis label   
df.plot
```

Most importantly, I would like to show the "choices" within each "category" in descending order of their "ratings", for example here "Charlie Category" would show charlie1, then charlie3, then charlie2.

I have honestly  looked online for solutions for about a week but can't find it. My current thoughts is that  I should convert the choices into factors but I haven't figured out how to do this properly.

Of secondary importance, it would be great if the "categories" could be listed, from the top down, "Alpha Category", "Bravo category", "Charlie Category" rather than in the inverse order as seems to occur when coordinates are flipped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer does not make use of the possibilities in `ggplot` to transform variables and scales (see @Metric's clean answer), but instead variables are transformed in beforehand.

**Within each Category, reorder choices based on ratings.** Check that 'choices' is a `character`. If it is a `factor`, you should convert to character with `as.character`, because reordering with a factor as input does not give us what we want (see below).

```
str(df$choices)
# chr [1:9] "alpha1" "alpha2" "alpha3" ...

library(plyr)
df <- ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(Categories), mutate,
            choices = reorder(choices, ratings))
```

**Reverse levels of 'Categories'**

```
df$Categories <- as.factor(df$Categories)
levels(df$Categories) <- rev(levels(df$Categories))
```

**Plot**

```
df.plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Categories, y = ratings, fill = choices)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), limits = c(0, 80)) +
  ylab("Ratings")  +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16))   

df.plot
```

[image]

**Edit following a comment from @Michael Bellhouse - "it appears alpha category is ranked but not bravo or charlie"**

When 'choices' is a character, the factor levels that are generated and reordered in `ddply` is based on each *subset* of 'choices'. Which works fine. On the other hand, when 'choices' is a factor in the original data, its levels are based on all levels present in the data. In `ddply` subset of 'choice' levels are then reordered, but the reordering takes place within the full set of levels. This leads to three sets of conflicting levels and only the first is used.

```
# reorder character version
ll <- dlply(.data = df, .variables = .(Categories), mutate,
            choices.ro = reorder(choices, ratings))

# check levels
lapply(ll, function(x) levels(x$choices.ro))
# $`Alpha Category`
# [1] "alpha1" "alpha3" "alpha2"
# 
# $`Bravo Category`
# [1] "bravo3" "bravo1" "bravo2"
# 
# $`Charlie Category`
# [1] "charlie2" "charlie3" "charlie1"


# choices as factor
df$choices.fac <- as.factor(df$choices)
levels(df$choices.fac)
# [1] "alpha1"   "alpha2"   "alpha3"   "bravo1"   "bravo2"   "bravo3"   "charlie1" "charlie2"
# [9] "charlie3"

# reorder factor version
ll <- dlply(.data = df, .variables = .(Categories), mutate,
            choices.fac.ro = reorder(choices.fac, ratings))

# reordering takes place _within_ each Category, but on the _full set_ of levels
# $`Alpha Category`
# [1] "alpha1"   "alpha3"   "alpha2"   "bravo1"   "bravo2"   "bravo3"   "charlie1" "charlie2"
# [9] "charlie3"
# This set of levels will be used in ggplot if you start with choices as a factor.
# Hence @Michael Bellhouse comment: "alpha category is ranked but not bravo or charlie"

# $`Bravo Category`
# [1] "bravo3"   "bravo1"   "bravo2"   "alpha1"   "alpha2"   "alpha3"   "charlie1" "charlie2"
# [9] "charlie3"
# 
# $`Charlie Category`
# [1] "charlie2" "charlie3" "charlie1" "alpha1"   "alpha2"   "alpha3"   "bravo1"   "bravo2"  
# [9] "bravo3"

# Because a factor only can have one set of levels,
# the first set is used - $`Alpha Category`
# Thus, relordered within category Alpha only.
```

Comment: I tried the code for the first question, but the ggplot looks the same

Comment: Hmm...I updated with the plot that popped out when I ran the code.

Comment: Check `levels(df$choices)` before and after the `ddply` call.

Comment: Yes, I see that it worked perfectly for you - just what I am looking for.  Upon further inspection, on my end it appears alpha category is ranked but not bravo or charlie.   Would you mind copying in your full code into my original code above, and posting it in full, please?

Comment: It seems that the problem with the `reorder`ing in `ddply` depends on whether you feed it with 'choices' as a factor or as a character. When I create your df, using `data.frame`, 'choices' becomes a character. This depends on the `stringsAsFactors` in `options`. I run it through `ddply` as a character, and out comes a seemingly correctly reordered factor. However, if I convert 'choices' to a factor _before_ `ddply` only the 'alpha' category is reordered. Strange.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code for the ggplot you posted above?  I tried experimenting with the before/after ddply but I must not be following what you are saying.  I am so close to a solution, but I just have to see the full code altogether.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Michael Bellhouse, I tried to explain the re-ordering issue a little bit better (see edit). Thanks for pointing this out to me! Factors can definitely be tricky... Cheers

Answer (score 14):

```
library(ggplot2)
df.plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Categories,y=reorder(choices,ratings), fill = choices)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Categories)))
```

[image]

Comment: can you please show me how to use reorder, how should I write the code in this case?

Comment: +1 to do everything in `ggplot` Nice! Will see if it is possible to get rid of my old habits preparing all the data _before_ the ggplot calls...

Comment: this is almost there but now my scaling doesn't work.  "says Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.  Can we find a way to work this back into it?                   df.plot<-df.plot+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,by=10),limits=c(0,80) ) + ylab("Ratings")  + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=16))

Comment: I got the same error. May be you need to make some adjustment there.